# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method logIn on channel com.roughike/flutter_facebook_login)

Tags: flutter

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(213)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method logIn on channel com.roughike/flutter_facebook_login)

Comment: Please check the guidelines of how to ask a question on StackOverflow and edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly type terminal `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` finally run your project with `flutter run`. These steps should solve your problem.

Comment: I try do this but not working again and display the same error

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure to follow step-by-step, like here:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_login_facebook

And please double-check the path:

```
/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
```

Is that set correctly? E.g.,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Name of the app </string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">123456789</string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb123456789</string>
</resources>
```