# Flutter : No implementation found for method login on channel app.meedu/flutter_facebook_auth

Tags: flutter, facebook-authentication

I am trying to use facebook auth in myy app with flutter.

I did all things in documentation.

also I tried to find solution here but nothing helped me ,for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71337659/unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implemen-tation-found-for-method) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68257773/unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-l)

I add this strings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">xxxxxxxxxxx</string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fbxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
    <string name="facebook_client_token">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
    <string name="app_name">xxxx</string>
</resources>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml I add this :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> // before application

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>

<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                    "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<queries>
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider" />
```

my function :

```
final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();
      if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
        accessToken = result.accessToken!;
        isLogined = true;
        final userData = await FacebookAuth.instance.getUserData();   
      } else {
        print(result.status);
        print(result.message);
      }
```

I get this error `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method login on channel app.meedu/flutter_facebook_auth)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the "No implementation" error is caused when you add a new package and do hot reload, or when the platform isn't supported. Try running the app from cold start.
If it still fails, I recommend using [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) package for authentication since it supports multiple providers including Facebook.

Answer (score -1):

From https://facebook.meedu.app/docs/5.x.x/android (where you can also find more relevant info):

> Upon installation of this plugin, configuration is needed on Android before running the project again. If this is not done, an error of **No implementation found** would show because the Facebook SDK on Android would throw an Exception error if the configuration is not yet defined. This error also locks the other plugins in your project, so if the plugin is not yet needed, either remove it or comment it out from the pubspec.yaml file.

So, when you add the flutter_facebook_auth plugin, you have to add in configuration to avoid this error.  This includes

in /android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">{your-app-id}</string>
<string name="facebook_client_token">YOUR_CLIENT_TOKEN</string>
```

in /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
```

for Android API 30+ also add

```
<manifest package="com.example.app">
    <queries>
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider" />
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

and Associate Your Package Name and Default Class with Your App in Facebook.

This got me past the error you mentioned.

Comment: @DanielWiddis I edited this answer to be a better answer.